# How to "sysprep" a Linux VM from inside that VM?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, esxi, sysprep

I need to prepare a Linux VM to create a template hosted on a VMware ESXi.

So far I found this [german virt-sysprep procedure](https://www-my--it--brain-de.translate.goog/wordpress/tag/virt-sysprep/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp) that syspreps the Linux VM but from outside the VM.

It says I need a Linux workstation to mount the VMFS (containing the VMDK file) with SSHFS and then run the `virt-sysprep` onto the VMDK file of the previously shutdown VM.

On a windows VM, I remember the `sysprep` operation was done from inside the VM before shutting it down.

Is there a method to "sysprep" a Linux VM from inside the VM ?

Comment: What's wrong with virt-sysprep ?

Comment: @harrymc Nothing wrong with `virt-sysprep`, I'm just not comfortable with mounting the production VMFS with write permissions. Indeed, the [german virt-sysprep procedure](https://www-my--it--brain-de.translate.goog/wordpress/tag/virt-sysprep/?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-US&_x_tr_pto=wapp) says `There is a risk of data loss due to corrupted VMDK files.`

Comment: It's easy enough to clone the VM before virt-sysprep.

Comment: @harrymc I guess I have to clone the VM each time I add new software and then run the `virt-sysprep` procedure.

Comment: This procedure is indicated if you don't want it to modify the VM.

Answer (score 3):

VMWare doesn't have an exact method like `sysprep`.
It has the
[virt-sysprep utility](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/virtualization_administration_guide/sect-guest_virtual_machine_disk_access_with_offline_tools-using_virt_sysprep)
for Linux VMs.

As it modifies the guest or disk image in-place, it's best to clone the VM.
See the VMWare article
[Clone an Existing Virtual Machine](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-1E185A80-0B97-4B46-A32B-3EF8F309BEED.html).